# How can I prevent eager text wrapping in absolutely positioned children?

Tags: css

I have a container of a fixed width and an absolutely positioned child containing text.  When it has text that's long enough to wrap then the browser wraps very eagerly; showing many more lines than necessary:

[image: Eager text wrap]

The only "solution" I've found so far is to give the hover container width: 90%.  But this is bad for short texts!

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbLvd7on/

Some HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  Container
  <div id="child">
    This is a long enough text to wrap.  I want it to wrap but I also want it to expand to 90% width and mostly fill its parent.  Why does it wrap so eagerly?
  </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#child {
  content: "";
  padding: 4px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 90%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the use of `left:50%`. An idea is to consider another wrapper for the text and center like below:

```css
#ex {
  position: relative;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: 90%;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 4px;
}
#after,
#before{
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  z-index: 1;
  text-align:center;
}

#before {
  top:auto;
  bottom:calc(100% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="ex">
  Container
  <div id="before">
    <span>Short text</span>
  </div>
  <div id="after">
    <span>This is a long enough text to wrap.  I want it to wrap but I also want it to expand to 90% width and mostly fill its parent.  Why does it wrap so eagerly?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way in case you cannot use extra element is to consider `fit-content` value within width (https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width):

```css
#ex {
  position: relative;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  color: black;
  width: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#ex::after,
#ex::before{
  content: "This is a long enough text to wrap.  I want it to wrap but I also want it to expand to 90% width and mostly fill its parent.  Why does it wrap so eagerly?";
  padding: 4px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width:fit-content;
  margin:0 auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 90%;
}

#ex::before {
  content: "Short text";
  top:auto;
  bottom: calc(100% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="ex">
  Container
</div>
```

Comment: Ah you're so right about the left: 50%.  Thank you!  Unfortunately I think this won't solve my issue because the use-case is using ::after so I can't add an extra container.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pru2m1yf/

Comment: @mark I added another solution but you need to pay attention to browser support

Answer (score 0):

Your parent container has width of `400px`. Keep it `100%`.